# How to test hypothesis for ordinal dependent variable and categorical independent variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, ordinal-data

I want to test the following hypothesis:
H1: Traditional business owners protect customers' personal information better than online business owners.

Here, indepedent variable is business (2 groups: online owners and traditional owners) and dependent variable is Access to information (ordinal: Strongly agree to Strongly disagree).
My data is not normal. Which statistical test should I use to test the above mentioned hypothesis?

Comment: Look into ordinal regression, search this site. Start with https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281619/linear-regression-or-ordinal-logistic-regression-to-predict-wine-rating-from-0