# Interpretation Bayesian Ordered Logistic model

Tags: regression, bayesian, interpretation, ordered-logit

I have a question about interpreting a Bayesian ordered logistic model. The outcome variable is ordinal, on a scale 1 - 5, and there are two categorical predictor variables, religion (4 levels) and country (3 levels). I would prefer to use level mean coding (and not create dummies) for the categorical predictors for the reasons McElreath gives in his [Statistical Rethinking](https://xcelab.net/rm/statistical-rethinking/), namely because in that case I'd assume there is more uncertainty about the non-reference categories as they'd include two paramaters (and hence priors).

This would give me the following simple model (loosely based on a model by McElreath in chapter 12 of the same book, and without bothering about choosing the right priors for now):

$$\displaystyle R_{i} \sim Orderedlogit(\phi_{i}, \kappa)$$

$$\displaystyle \frac{Pr(y_{i}\geq \kappa)}{1 - Pr(y_{i}\geq \kappa)} = \alpha_{\kappa} - \phi_{i}$$

$$\displaystyle \phi = \gamma_{country[i]} + \beta_{religion[i]}$$

4 priors for the cutpoints:

$$\displaystyle \kappa = Normal(0,1)$$

3 priors, one for each level, for 'country':

$$\displaystyle \gamma = Normal(0,1)$$

4 priors, one for each level, for 'religion':

$$\displaystyle \beta = Normal(0,1)$$

From reading other posts (and very good responses) [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89474/interpretation-of-ordinal-logistic-regression) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94581/plot-and-interpret-ordinal-logistic-regression?rq=1), I think I understand how to interpret the results for the cutpoints. So, my questions concern the interpretation of the coefficients (and their posteriors) for the non-dummy-coded categorical predictors.

1. I am mainly interested in the effects of the 'country' variable. However, the result for that parameter is inevitably entangled with the other parameters in the model. I could get posterior predictive samples for each of the levels of 'country', but those samples would still depend on the values of the other predictor. So, my question is: **Can I get an estimate (presumably of probabilities for each of the cutpoints) for each of the levels of country, independently from the other variable, and how?** In short, I want an estimate of the effect of 'country' independently from the religion of the participants.
2. My second question is related but more general: **How to interpret the coefficients for each of the levels of country?** That is, how to explain what the coefficients mean without the use of posterior predictive samples. Interpretation is easier, I suppose, if the predictors are dummy coded, but I would like to avoid that for the reason discussed above. And even if they were dummy-coded, I'm not sure they can be interpreted independently from the other predictor.

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that using normal priors for the intercepts is a great idea.  I know it fails as the number of Y categories increases.  In the R [`rmsb` package](https://hbiostat.org/R/rmsb) I use Dirichlet priors for the probabilities that are induced by the intercepts, which makes sampling faster, automatically forces ordering of intercepts, and works well for large numbers of Y categories.  But I don't handle ordinal predictors explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. For now, I've just make sure to manually set initial values for the cutpoints, and that way the sampling works. But a Dirichlet prior might indeed be better.

Comment: Yes, and initial values can be very hard to choose when there are many predictors or some of them have multiple basis functions (e.g., splines).