# Plotting results of ordered logistic regression analysis

Tags: r, logistic, data-visualization, ordered-logit

I tried to plot the results of an ordered logistic regression analysis by calculating the probabilities of endorsing every answer category of the dependent variable (6-point Likert scale, ranging from "1" to "6"). However, I've received strange probabilities when I calculated the probabilities based on this formula: $\rm{Pr}(y_i \le k|X_i) = \rm{logit}^{-1}(X_i\beta)$.

Below you see how exactly I tried to calculate the probabilities and plot the results of the ordered logistic regression model (`m2`) that I fitted using the `polr` function (`MASS` package). The probabilities (`probLALR`) that I calculated and used to plot an "expected mean score" are puzzling as the expcected mean score in the plot increases along the RIV.st continuum while the coefficient for `RIV.st` is negative (-0.1636). I would have expected that the expected mean score decreases due to the negative main effect of `RIV.st` and the irrelevance of the interaction terms for the low admiration and low rivalry condition (LALR) of the current 2 by 2 design (first factor = `f.adm`; second factor = `f.riv`; dummy coding 0 and 1).

Any idea of how to make sense of the found pattern? Is this the right way to calculate the probabilities? The way I used the intercepts in the formula to calculate the probabilities might be problematic (cf., [Negative coefficient in ordered logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38087/negative-coefficient-in-ordered-logistic-regression)).

```
m2 <- polr(short.f ~ 1 + f.adm*f.riv + f.adm*RIV.st + f.riv*RIV.st, data=sampleNS)

# f.adm  = dummy (first factor of 2 by 2 design);
# f.riv  = dummy (second factor of 2 by 2 design);
# RIV.st = continuous predictor (standardized)
summary(m2)
Coefficients:
                Value Std. Error t value
f.adm1         1.0203    0.14959  6.8203
f.riv1        -0.8611    0.14535 -5.9240
RIV.st        -0.1636    0.09398 -1.7403
f.adm1:f.riv1 -1.2793    0.20759 -6.1625
f.adm1:RIV.st  0.0390    0.10584  0.3685
f.riv1:RIV.st  0.6989    0.10759  6.4953

Intercepts:
    Value    Std. Error t value 
1|2  -2.6563   0.1389   -19.1278
2|3  -1.2139   0.1136   -10.6898
3|4  -0.3598   0.1069    -3.3660
4|5   0.9861   0.1121     8.7967
5|6   3.1997   0.1720    18.6008
```

Here you see how I tried to calculate the probabilities (`probLALR`) for 1 of the 4 conditions of the 2 by 2 design:

```
inv.logit  <- function(x){ return(exp(x)/(1+exp(x))) }
Pred       <- seq(-3, 3, by=0.01)
b = c(-2.6563,-1.2139,-0.3598,0.9861,3.1997) # intercepts of model m2
a = c(1.0203,-0.8611,-0.1636,-1.2793,0.0390,0.6989) # coefficients of m2
probLALR   <- data.frame(matrix(NA,601,5))
for (k in 1:5){ 
    probLALR[,k] <- inv.logit(b[k] + a[1]*0 + a[2]*0 + 
                               a[3]*Pred  + a[4]*0*0 + 
                               a[5]*Pred*0 + a[6]*Pred*0)
}

plot(Pred,probLALR[,1],type="l",ylim=c(0,1))   # p(1)
lines(Pred,probLALR[,2],col="red")             # p(1 or 2)
lines(Pred,probLALR[,3],col="green")           # P(1 or 2 or 3)
lines(Pred,probLALR[,4],col="orange")          # P(1 or 2 or 3 or 4)
lines(Pred,probLALR[,5],col="orange")          # P(1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5)

# option response functions:

orc = matrix(NA,601,6)
orc[,6] = 1-probLALR[,5]        # prob of 6
orc[,5]= probLALR[,5]-probLALR[,4]  # prob of 5
orc[,4]= probLALR[,4]-probLALR[,3]  # prob of 4
orc[,3]= probLALR[,3]-probLALR[,2]  # prob of 3
orc[,2]= probLALR[,2]-probLALR[,1]  # prob of 2
orc[,1]= probLALR[,1]           # prob of 1


plot(Pred,orc[,1],type="l",ylim=c(0,1))   # p(1)
lines(Pred,orc[,2],col="red")             # p(2)
lines(Pred,orc[,3],col="green")           # P(3)
lines(Pred,orc[,4],col="orange")          # P(4)
lines(Pred,orc[,5],col="purple")          # P(5)
lines(Pred,orc[,6],col="purple")          # P(6)

# mean score

mean = orc[,1]*1+orc[,2]*2+orc[,3]*3+orc[,4]*4+orc[,5]*5+orc[,6]*6
plot(Pred,mean,type="l",xlab="RIV.st",ylab="expected mean score",ylim=c(1,6))
```

Comment: Could you post a reproducible example?

Comment: That still isn't reproducible. In the meantime, let me just point out that `predict(m2, type ="prob")` computes the probabilities for you. Also package 'effects' can be used for effect displays of models fitted by `polr()`.

Comment: Dear Achim, thanks a lot for the hint to the predict function. I didn't know that you can predict probabilities. That solves the whole issue.

Comment: @AchimZeileis: I've now updated my question and code. The results are still puzzling when I calculate the prob by hand because the expected mean scure curve is increasing even though it should be decreasing.
The results are different when I use the `predict(m2,type="prob)` (see my answer below). @Aniko

Comment: See also: [Interpretation of ordinal logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/89474/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Wilco Emons for the following solution to the problem:

In `polr` the cumulative link model is parameterized a bit different than in Agresti’s book that is referred to.  The problem can be easily solved by changing the code line:

```
probLALR[,k] <- inv.logit(b[k] +  a[1]*0 + a[2]*0 + a[3]*Pred + a[4]*0*0 + 
                                  a[5]*Pred*0 + a[6]*Pred*0                )
```

into

```
probLALR[,k] <- inv.logit(b[k] - (a[1]*0 + a[2]*0 + a[3]*Pred + a[4]*0*0 + 
                                  a[5]*Pred*0 + a[6]*Pred*0)               )
```

Thanks also to Achim Zeileis for his suggestion to use `predict(m2, type="prob")`!
Below you will find a way to calculate the probabilities by the means of the `predict()` function:

```
Pred             <- seq(-3, 3, by=0.01)
PRED.LALR        <- data.frame(rep(NA,601))
PRED.LALR$f.adm  <- as.factor(rep(0,601))
PRED.LALR$f.riv  <- as.factor(rep(0,601))
PRED.LALR$RIV.st <- Pred
prob.LALR        <- predict(m2,PRED.LALR,type="prob")

scoreLALR        <- prob.LALR[,1]*1 + prob.LALR[,2]*2 + prob.LALR[,3]*3 + 
                    prob.LALR[,4]*4 + prob.LALR[,5]*5 + prob.LALR[,6]*6
plot(Pred, scoreLALR, col="green", ylim=c(1,6))
```