# Ordinal logistic regression and its interpretation

Tags: r, logistic, interpretation, ordered-logit

I fitted an ordinal logistic regression but I'm unable to interpret the coefficients. Can anyone assist in this regard? Here is the output generated:

```
Call:
polr(formula = factor(grade) ~ factor(Month) + Day, data = myData, 
    Hess = TRUE)

Coefficients:
                  Value Std. Error t value
factor(Month)4 1.405114    0.51547  2.7259
Day            0.007672    0.01944  0.3947

Intercepts:
    Value   Std. Error t value
1|2 -0.6785  0.7019    -0.9667
2|3  1.6767  0.7162     2.3412

Residual Deviance: 333.602 
AIC: 341.602
```

The grade is factored:

1 = good
2 = very good
3 = excellent

Month is factored:

3 = March
4 = April

The grade is the response while month and day are my explanatory variables.

Comment: This might help you: [Negative coefficient in ordered logistic regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/38087/).

Comment: I don't get you. can you explain please?

Comment: There's a lot of information at the link that can help you interpret OLR models. Can you be more specific about what you need to know? Eg, do you know what a standard error is?

Comment: Yes, I know what standard error is which is the standard deviation  divided by the square root of n. My question is "How do i interpret the coefficient values for Day and Month with respect to the response variable which in this case is the grade?

Comment: the standard error you reported in your question is **not** the standard deviation divivded by the square root of n.

Comment: The standard error there is the error of the regression model right?