# How do I plot simple slopes for a significant interaction term in an ordinal logistic regression model?

Tags: interaction, ordinal-data

There are a variety of excel files allowing users to plot simple slopes with various types of estimates (regression coefficients, odds ratios, etc.). I'm wondering if such an excel file for a logit exists. If not, any recommendations on how to create one? Thanks!

Comment: Outside of some canned excel file that is supposed to do this for you, do you know how to compute simple effects from an interaction model?  Do you understand the logic of it?  Would you know how to plot them once you've computed them?

Comment: First, make sure you know how your software is fitting the ordinal regression (cf, [Negative coefficient in ordered logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/38130/)). Then calculate the simple effects.  Then you can make plots (cf, [Interpretation of ordinal logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/89485/)).  They might be rather busy for ordinal regression, though.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica, yes, I understand how to compute simple effects from an interaction model. I'm not sure how to plot them for logits.